# Adobe XD element export to flutter issue

Tags: android-studio, flutter, export, adobe-xd

**The Issue**
After I installed Flutter Export in Adobe XD and Flutter and Dart in Android Studio, I wanted to Export All Widgets in XD. After attaching the right folder in the upcoming window the following text shows up: " Could not find dependencies entry in pubspec.yaml for : adobe_xd." Any suggestions how I can add it into the .yaml file? Because all of my tries failed. Thanks for responding <3

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `adobe_xd` https://pub.dev/packages/adobe_xd package into your Flutter project's `pubspec.yaml` file